# Make Documents Directory Files Visible To Another App Via UIDocumentsPicker

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, icloud

**What I Have Done:**

I'm developing an application where it transfers different type of files (Eg: Images, Word Docs, Videos) between iOS devices. I'm keeping those files inside the app. I have successfully implemented iCloud Drive to share files from other applications (Eg: Documents). This is how it's done,

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker =
     [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:
     @[(__bridge NSString *) kUTTypeContent,
     (__bridge NSString *) kUTTypeData,
     (__bridge NSString *) kUTTypePackage,
     @"com.apple.iwork.pages.pages",
     @"com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers",
     @"com.apple.iwork.keynote.key"] 
     inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
documentPicker.delegate = self;
documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
[documentPicker release];
```

**Objective:**

I want to make my application files (Eg: Images, Word Docs, Videos) store inside the folder "Documents/Files" to be accessible via another app (Like Documents).

**R & D:**

This is the [reference doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/FileProvider.html) I'm reading to achieve this. I manage to create a folder of my app by editing the *info.plist*. But couldn't display my files stored inside documents directory.

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to make the files I have stored inside documents directory visible to another app via UIDocumentsPicker or something else?.
- If it is possible, is there a much easier reference document for me to read? (The current one that I'm reading is a bit difficult to understand).

Thanks.